Markov Decision Process and Message Passing
I am reading the book “Bayesian Reasoning and Machine Learning”. I am reading Chapter 7.5 on Markov Decision process. I come from an optimal stopping / optimal control background and am familiar with Bellman principles etc. Essentially, the idea is that you start from the end and work backward.
What I find puzzling is that application to Bellamn principle (the backward stepping) are explained in term of message passing, where the messages are the value function of the state.
Is there any particular reason why this things are expressed this way? I felt that I must be missing the point here.
